# Shell app not loading all it's component after login window in WPF prism

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, prism, bootstrapper

We have a login window in our application that will be loaded before loading the shell application. After authentication, that is only the time that the shell window must appear. But sadly, after authentication, the shell window does not load all of its component. Here is the screen capture:

[image: Here is the screen capture]

The code below that I used after logging in, the shell application will show and run.

```
 protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        Window login = new LoginView();
        var loginVM = new LoginViewModel(new LoginAuth());
        loginVM.LoginCompleted += (sender, args) =>
        {
            login.Close();
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
        };
        login.DataContext = loginVM;
        login.ShowDialog();
    }
```

My WPF application has an app.xaml that loads the shell.xaml code.

```
<Application x:Class="...Shell.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:...Shell">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/...Presentation;component/Styles/ExtendedTextBoxStyle.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/..;component/Styles/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

It should have a content at least. The glimpse code of the shell.xaml below.

[image]

I should have a menu in the left side after the authentication from the login window but it does not load all the components.

[image]

Is there any missed out code from here are is there any other implementation that can fix the issue that I have? Thanks!

Comment: This may be a race-condition. Can you try what happens if you `Show` the login window (instead of `ShowDialog`), so that you're not blocking?

Answer (score 0):

`ShowDialog` is a blocking call, thus stopping the bootstrapping process. You should use `Show` to show the login window.

```
protected override void InitializeShell()
{
    Window login = new LoginView();
    var loginVM = new LoginViewModel(new LoginAuth());
    loginVM.LoginCompleted += (sender, args) =>
    {
        login.Close();
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    };
    login.DataContext = loginVM;
    // problem below:
    login.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Using .Show will make my shell application run through wherein I want to continue running the shell after authentication from my login window.

Comment: But nothing of the (shell-) application will be visible except for the login window, so that should not be a problem.

Comment: @mm8: Yes. Is there any implementation that is missing in my code that can fix it? Thanks!

Comment: If the contents come from modules and those are not initialized because everyone waits for the login window, that may well be a race condition. If the modules load fast enough, they'll be in the shell when it is shown, if not, the shell will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

> It should have a content at least.

Should it? You need to add something to the region(s) somewhere, for example right after the `ShowDialog()` method has returned. And you should not call `Application.Current.MainWindow.Show()`. Prism will show the shell window for you once the call to the `ShowDialog()` method of the LoginView has returned. Try this:

```
protected override Window CreateShell()
{
    return new ShellWindow();
}

protected override void InitializeShell(Window shell)
{
    Window login = new LoginView();
    var loginVM = new LoginViewModel(new LoginAuth());
    loginVM.LoginCompleted += (sender, args) =>
    {
        login.Close();
    };
    login.DataContext = loginVM;
    login.ShowDialog();

    IRegionManager regionManager = Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
    IRegion region = regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.ContentRegion];
    if (region != null)
        region.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "test content..." });
}
```

Comment: This seems to use the Prism 7 application api while the OP uses the Prism 6 bootstrapper api.

Comment: @mm8: Will try this fix tho. Thanks!

Comment: @mm8: I edited the comment that you have. In the shell app, I should have a menu in the left but it does not load after authentication in the login window.

Comment: @jololandayan: Edit your question. Are you populating the MainMenuRegion? And what's the value of MenuVisibility?

Comment: @mm8: Yes I'm populating it through this code of MainModule under my shell application.

 public void Initialize()
        {
            this.regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainMenuRegion, typeof (MainMenuView));
            this.regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.CrumbsRegion, typeof (CrumbsView));
        }

Comment: @jololandayan: Did you try my sample code? Just replace RegionNames.ContentRegion with RegionNames.MainMenuRegion.

Comment: @mm8: Tried your code, but it does not fix the issue. :( The code of shell app  is existing already and the login module is the new module that we have to implement. We are encountering a problem whenever we try to have the login window first before the shell app will appear.

Comment: @jololandayan: What issue? It certainly works for me, i.e. you see content in the content region once the user has logged in. Did you get rid of Application.Current.MainWindow.Show?

Comment: @mm8: The main window suddenly closed after the login window after I removed Application.Current.MainWindow.Show.

Comment: @jololandayan:  You mean the shell window? So this is opened *before* the login window?

Comment: @mm8: My login window appears but after authentication (this is where the LoginCompleted event argument) is done, it suddenly closes.

Comment: @mm8: I have already implemented a new logic in the method of this.app.Start wherein, I must show the login window first. The instance is that, in parallel, the shell app would appear first and then the login window, respectively but you won't be able to go to the shell app unless you are authenticated in the login window.